# Prove the Superposition Principle for Nonhomogeneous Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y_1$ is a solution to $Ly_1 = f(x)$ and $y_2$ is a solution to $Ly_2 = g(x)$

Show that
$y = y_1 + y_2$ solves $Ly = f(x) + g(x)$.

So, assuming that the linear operator $L$ is the same for both:
$$\frac {Ly_1}{f(x)}=1=\frac {Ly_2}{g(x)}$$
Then, setting them equal to each other: $$\frac {Ly_1}{f(x)}=\frac {Ly_2}{g(x)}$$
Therefore: $$Ly_1g(x)=Ly_2f(x)$$
But I don't know how to go about proving the principle.

Comment: Start with $\,L(y)=L(y_1+y_2)\,$ and use that $\,L\,$ is a *linear* operator.